# How to get an ImageView's touch event back to the ImageView's parent activity

Tags: android, android-activity, imageview, touch-event

I have an `Activity` with a layout containing a custom `ImageView` and a few other views (a `ListView` and a couple other `TextView`s).  Depending on where the user touches the `ImageView`, I need to change the contents of the `ListView` and the `TextView`s.  I have an `onTouchEvent` listener working fine in the `ImageView` class, but somehow I need to signal the Activity class that the touch event happened in the `ImageView` and pass it some data...then the Activity can properly adjust all the other views.

I thought about trying to return "false" from the `ImageView`'s `onTouchEvent` handler, thus letting the event matriculate up to the ImageView's parent view, but I don't think it has a parent view...just a parent `ViewGroup` (`LinearLayout`).

This feels like a design issue to me, but I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a built-in way to do this. Write your image view class to all for a call-back to be registered after it changes its content. Then in the activity's `onCreate` method, retrieve the image view and register the activity as the call-back object. When the image view finishes handling the touch event, it can just invoke the call-back method.

Here's a sketch of how this might work:

```
public class MyImageView extends ImageView {
    public interface OnImageChangedListener {
         public void imageChanged(MyImageView view);
    }

    private OnImageChangedListener mChangeListener;

    public void setOnImageChangedListener(OnImageChangedListener listener) {
        mChangeListener = listener;
    }

    // inside your OnTouchListener:
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            // make updates, then, if warranted:
            if (mChangeListener != null) {
                mChangeListener.imageChanged(MyImageView.this);
            }
        }
```

Then just have your activity declared to implement `MyImageView.OnImageChangedListener` and call `imageView.setOnImageChangedListener(this)` after finding the image view (probably using `findViewById`).

Obviously, you can save some typing by shortening the method names. More importantly, you can, if it would be useful, add additional arguments to the call-back method.

Comment: Thanks Ted! Your solution sounds good. Now I need to learn how in create callbacks in Android.  I **think** I should be able to handle this.  :-)

Comment: @BryanGreenway - I added some sample code, in case it will help.

Comment: Fantastic help!!  This made short work of this for me, and educated me along the way.  Works great.  Thanks again, Ted.

Comment: @BryanGreenway - Glad it worked. You might consider marking the question as solved by accepting my answer. See [the faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) for info about accepting answers.